# filename contains Chinese characters unable to be compiled by XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, compiling, texstudio, windows, filesystem-access

windows 10

TeXstudio 2.12.16

texlive2019 default installation

it said:

> Could not start Build & View:XeLaTeX: xelatex.exe -synctex=1
>   -interaction=nonstopmode "hashujixian-副本".tex

but it can compiles the filename with pure ASCIIcode

how to solve this problem?

Comment: check if your texmf.cnf contains at the end `command_line_encoding = utf-8`.

Comment: works,thank you @ Ulrike Fischer

Comment: If this helped you should perhaps update your system: texlive has just added this setting as default in the texmf.cnf.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comments.